# jstring is not working

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native

I am doing this code in HelloWorld.c

```
#include "com_testndk_HelloWorld.h"

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_testndk_HelloWorld_messageFromNativeCode (JNIEnv * env, jobject jObj)

{
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello World!");
}
```

It show me error on `JNIEXPORT jstring` and when i compile ndk then it show me this error
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `<jni.h>`

Comment: Your environment isn't setup correctly.  Try following a tutorial: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_NDK.html

Comment: I set my environment accordingly and i updte my question as well , if you please guide

Comment: @Ahmad I see nothing about the include path. Please find and follow a straightforward tutorial on the subject to configure your environment correctly.